# Why aren't any networks showing when I type airodump-ng <card name>

Tags: networking, kali-linux, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

So I am new in Kali Linux and want to learn the basics. I bought a TP-Link dual boot USB adapter. I can see the device when I type iwconfig wlan0. I can run it on monitor mode also. It works fine. But when I type airodump-ng wlan0 it doesn't give me any errors however it doesn't show any networks either. So I did some research and tried the stuff I found online such as airodump-ng mon0 but when I run the command it gives me an error such as `no such device'. What should I do to see the networks around me? Is there a problem with my wireless card? Please help. And thanks for reading.

I think the guy in the video has the same problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpzZe7PO8TY

Comment: If the provided answer worked for you, please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it - also see [what should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the following codes

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Depending on the version of Kali your monitor mode will be either *wlan0mon* for newer versions or *mon0* for older versions. Since you do not get any output on using mon0, use

```
airodump-ng wlan0mon
```

You can find the name of the monitor mode using ifconfig after using airmon-ng. It will specify the new network interface. The person in the video made the same mistake as he was specifying *mon0* instead of *wlan0mon*.